# Flutter. Applying a different configuration for Testflight and the App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, testflight

The task is to use different API URLs inside the Flutter application for the app installed through the Testflight and for the app installed through the App Store.

Libraries like: [store_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/store_checker) and [detect_testflight](https://pub.dev/packages/detect_testflight)

do not give 100% results, and I cannot be sure that they will not stop correctly detecting the installation source after the next update.

I also cannot rely on the [kReleaseMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html) **constant**, since there is no way to create a build that compiled in debug mode and uploads it on a Testflight. This can only be done in release mode.

Using custom configuration files and setting up the [.gitattributes](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b) file also seems like a perversion, and is not suitable because, besides the local repositories of many developers, bitbucket is used, in which I cannot add my merge driver. Also, there is no guarantee that other developers will use this driver.

Tell me a simple and concise way to implement this? Didn't Apple come up with the idea that developers would need to use different settings for builds in Testflight and in App Store?